# WYSIWYG for Sharepoint graph explorer API

Tags: sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api

I am using microsoft sharepoint to host excel files on cloud. While for a project reason I am using Graph Explorer REST APIs to read and write contents to sharepoint.

Simple text scenarios:
For reading, I use the url of form

```
             GRAPH_EXPLORER_URL
            + SITE_ID
            + "/drives/"
            + LIBRARY_ID
            + "/items/"
            + FILE_ID
            + "/workbook/worksheets('"
            + WORKSHEET + "')/range(address='" +
              RANGE + "') "
```

I do get the contents in the range
and for write, I use the same URL, but with PATCH method, with the contents

```
{
values:[["1","2"]]
}
```

So the issue I have, is how to use WYSIWYG in API calls
Eg:
[image: WYSIWYG editor]

This is from a WYSIWYG editor.
When I copy and paste this directly to sharepoint, I do get what I wanted
[image]

But I am not sure, how to achieve this using API calls.
As when it considers this as a plain text, and even if I enter equivalent HTML code produced by
WYSIWYG in it, it considers as plain text.

I did explore https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/rangefont?view=graph-rest-1.0
but, this applies to the whole cell and not to the section of texts in the cell.

Can anyone explain How to achieve this?

Comment: The closest one i see is that you can apply to a whole cell, not to the section of texts in the cell.

Comment: AFAIK, i failed to see the above functionality exists at this point. I love to see if someone comes up with other ideas.

Comment: If nothing works, i would suggest you to file Microsoft Uservoice - so that it can be considered for implementation. Here's the [uservoice link where you can file it](https://microsoftgraph.uservoice.com/forums/920506-microsoft-graph-feature-requests?category_id=359629). Once you file it, share it here  - so it can be useful to the community as well.

Answer (score 1):

The closest one i see is that you can apply to a whole cell, not to the section of texts in the cell. AFAIK, i failed to see the above functionality exists at this point. If nothing works, i would suggest you to file Microsoft Uservoice - so that it can be considered for implementation. Here's the [uservoice link where you can file](https://microsoftgraph.uservoice.com/forums/920506-microsoft-graph-feature-requests?category_id=359629) it. Once you file it, share it here - so it can be useful to the community as well.

Comment: https://microsoftgraph.uservoice.com/forums/920506-microsoft-graph-feature-requests/suggestions/42157591-wysiwyg-for-cells-using-graph-explorer-api